# Pandas resample not adding up

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains closing stocks prices for 461 stocks.

```
In [43]: pdata
Out[43]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3418 entries, 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2013-02-06 00:00:00
Columns: 461 entries, AKM to ZIM
dtypes: float64(461)
```

I am ranking the stocks on returns over the last 130 days and selecting the top 10 performers

```
In [44]: mom_ret = pdata.shift(1).pct_change(130)

In [45]: rank = mom_ret.rank(axis=1,ascending=False,method='first')

In [46]: rank[rank<=10]=1

In [47]: rank[rank>10]=0
```

If I take the sum of the rows, they all equal 10 as I would expect.

```
In [48]: x=rank.groupby(rank.sum(axis=1))

In [49]: x.sum()
Out[49]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, 10.0 to 10.0          # all rows sum to 10 as expected.
Columns: 461 entries, AKM to ZIM
dtypes: float64(461)
```

I then resample the dataframe as below

```
In [50]: port = rank.resample('20B', how='first')

In [51]: y=port.groupby(port.sum(axis=1))
```

But now when I sum the rows they don't all add up to 10?

```
In [52]: y.sum()
Out[52]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4 entries, 10.0 to 13.0          # 4 entries ranging between 10 and 13??
Columns: 461 entries, AKM to ZIM
dtypes: float64(461)
```

I don't understand why this would happen. Have I done something wrong or is this a bug?

I just realised that if I replace NaN's with 0, I don't have the problem.

```
In [67]: rank=rank.fillna(0)

In [68]: x=rank.groupby(rank.sum(axis=1))

In [69]: x.sum()
Out[69]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, 0.0 to 10.0     # 2 entries, 0 and 10
Columns: 461 entries, AKM to ZIM
dtypes: float64(461)

In [70]: port = rank.resample('20B', how='first')

In [71]: y=port.groupby(port.sum(axis=1))

In [72]: y.sum()
Out[72]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, 0.0 to 10.0    # 2 entries again, 0 and 10
Columns: 461 entries, AKM to ZIM
dtypes: float64(461)
```

But I would like to resample without filling in NaN's with 0. Is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to include some sample data (for `pdata` so we can have a look at it)?

Comment: you can download the data here:

Comment: Oops https://www.dropbox.com/l/xHxnfVVEFNFokFSB Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing this behavior is because the `how=first` takes the first non-na value, from each column. This is why filling the NAs with 0s will get you to the correct answer. To get the behavior you want without filling NAs, you can pass a custom function to `how` and just the first entry regardless of whether it's NA or not:

```
In [47]: port = rank.resample('20B', how=lambda x: x.ix[0])

In [48]: y=port.groupby(port.sum(axis=1))

In [49]: y.sum()
Out[49]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, 10.0 to 10.0
Columns: 461 entries, AKM to ZIM
dtypes: float64(461)
```